# Edit time value and add the week day in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove `.` between `p` and `m` and `.` after` in time.

Input:

```
<xml>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>MKTDATQ - NZX Market Data. Prepared at 2019-06-27 17:30:25</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</xml>
```

Output Should be:

```
<root>
  <fieldSet name="DataCompiledTime" value="5:30pm Thursday, June 27, 2019"/>
</root>
```

Tried code:

```
<root>
  <date>
    <fieldSet name="DataCompiledTime" value="{table/tr/td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Market Data.')] /format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(concat(substring(text(), string-length(text())- 18, 10),'T', substring(text(), string-length(text()) - 7,  string-length(text())))), '[h1]:[m01][P],[FNn], [MNn] [D], [Y]')}"/>
  </date>
</root>
```

My output:

```
<root>
  <fieldSet name="DataCompiledTime" value="5:30p.m., Thursday, June 27, 2019"/>
</root>
```

I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try This** [P] to [Pn,2-2]

```
 <root>
        <date>
            <fieldSet name="DataCompiledTime" value="{table/tr/td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Market Data.')] /format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(concat(substring(text(), string-length(text())- 18, 10),'T', substring(text(), string-length(text()) - 7,  string-length(text())))), '[h1]:[m01][Pn,2-2] [FNn], [MNn] [D], [Y]')}"/>
        </date>
    </root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't - and won't have - any other dots in your date string, you can easily use the `translate` function removing all dots from the result string of `format-dateTime`. So try this code

```
<root>
    <date>
        <fieldSet name="DataCompiledTime" value="{table/tr/td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Market Data.')]/translate(format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(concat(substring(text(), string-length(text())- 18, 10),'T', substring(text(), string-length(text()) - 7,  string-length(text())))), '[h1]:[m01][P],[FNn], [MNn] [D], [Y]'),'.','')}"/>
    </date>
</root>
```

which core change is

```
.../translate(format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(concat(substring(text(), string-length(text())- 18, 10),'T', substring(text(), string-length(text()) - 7,  string-length(text())))), '[h1]:[m01][P],[FNn], [MNn] [D], [Y]'),'.','')
```

which removes all dots from the `dateTime` string.

Comment: The other answer is better, but I do leave this one here for completeness.